# NFluent Check only a few members of an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, specflow, nfluent

I am writing unit tests with [Specflow 3](https://specflow.org/), to test a method that query data in db and I use [NFluent](http://www.n-fluent.net/) to have nice assertions methods.

**Is there any way to smoothly test equality over a few members of an object ?**

There is a method called *HasFieldsWithSameValues* but I found nothing in their wiki that explains how to use it thoroughly. There is a Excluding("fieldNames","etc",...) method that we can chain, but I would have to exclude over 20 public members.

Here is my feature file ( functionnal scenario, Gherkin syntax )

```
Scenario: TimeSheet_001_SearchForExistingTimeSheet
    When I search for timesheet with id 31985
    Then I get the following timesheet
    | id    | StatutPaid | StatutFact |
    | 31985 | Paid       | None       |
```

Then I have the methods called by this code bloc :

```
    [When(@"I search for timesheet with id (.*)")]
    public void WhenJeChercheLeReleveDHeureAvecLId(int id)
    {
        var result = GetTimeSheetDetailQuery(id);
        timeSheetContext.Result = result;
    }

    [Then(@"I get the following timesheet")]
    public void ThenJObtiensLeReleveDHeureSuivant(Table table)
    {
        var sut = table.CreateInstance<TimeSheetDetail>();
        Check.That(sut).HasFieldsWithSameValues<TimeSheetDetail>().Fields.IsEqualTo(timeSheetContext.Result);
    }
```

The problem is that TimeSheetDetail is a VERY detailed object, I just need to check for 3 members for this case of test. 
is there a way to write for example

```
//this
Check.That(sut)
.HasFieldsWithSameValues<myType>("Id","StatusPaid","StatusFact")
.IsEqualTo(timeSheetContext.Result);

//instead of this
Check.That(sut.Id).IsEQualTo(timeSheetContext.Result.Id);
Check.That(sut.StatusPaid).IsEQualTo(timeSheetContext.Result.StatusPaid);
Check.That(sut.StatusFact).IsEQualTo(timeSheetContext.Result.StatusFact);
```

Comment: Why not write the code exactly as you have it, making the assertions on the properties one-by-one? I think you are over complicating this.

Comment: For now I did, but I would like to use NFluent assertion library the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of things, the exact functionality that you're looking for isn't directly supported by NFluent. This sounds like a good candidate for using C# extension methods, and fortunately NFluent [supports extension methods](http://www.n-fluent.net/).

The gist of the idea is that you can implement a method that contains the logic that you're trying to have, and this method can be directly called by NFluent in order to achieve the syntax that's *closer* to what you're looking for (if not exactly what you're looking for). After implementing such method, you'll be able to make a call like so:

```
Check.That(sut).HasFieldsWithSameValues(timeSheetContext.Result, "Id", "StatusPaid", "StatusFact");
```

The extension method's prototype would be something like this:

```
public static ICheckLink<ICheck<Object>> HasFieldsWithSameValues(this ICheck<Object> check, myType myObject, params string[] fieldsList)
```

Note that you  may be able to get the *exact* syntax that you're looking for, but you'll have to do a little bit more work to figure out how to do that in the context of extension methods.

Find out more about C# extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Find an example of how to implement NFluent extension methods [here](http://www.jasondeoliveira.com/2014/06/visual-c-unit-tests-how-to-extend.html).

Comment: Thanks I was about to add a new Check for a different reason. Their documentation link on extension drives me on a 404 :')

Comment: @aurelienjo I updated the link for "how to implement NFluent extension methods". The rest of the links work for me :'(

Comment: I found this after my 404 issues it is nice indeed

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve desired results using an **anonymous type** for the expected value.

```
Check.That(sut).HasFieldsWithSameValues(new {Id=1, StatusPaid = true, StatusFact = "Paid"});
```

In this way, you can focus the comparison of the fields of interests.

If you need to make many check like this, you should contemplate creating a simple dedicated type for this instead of an anonymous one.